# In a given binary, what is an exported symbol?

Tags: windows, assembly

Can anybody provide a definitive description of what an "exported symbol" is with respect to an executable binary, and NOT a library?

Answer (score 1):

They are the same thing.  You export a procedure in a dll so other code can call that procedure by name/ordinal from the dll/lib.  You do the same thing with an exe, you can export functions to be used the same way.

[image]

Comment: What program did you use to produce this image?
Also, what sense does it make to have exports for a given exe, if you can't dynamically load any given exe like a dll in order to make use of an exe's exports? Also, I'm guessing that there isn't any sense and that the convention is that the creators know what they're doing and either make a dll or exe. Is this right?